# Serving Halal and non Halal food alonside eachother

Tags: food

I am looking to open a food outlet in a diverse part of London and was wondering what are peoples views on me serving non Halal food alongside Halal food. The menu will be about 95% Halal but for the restraunt to serve its purpose the 5% has to be non halal, which will be absolutely seperate to Halal food in every way possible. The entire purpose of the project is to bring the local community together in the healthiest way possible so there will be no alcohol served.

Comment: Are you a Muslim?

Comment: I am not, sorry I should of made that clear